# Slick slider starting with a left offset

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

I am working on a template which is bootstrap based. I need to set up a full width slick slider, but its initial state should start at the left edge of the content container, and then progressively slider further left.

I tried to represent what needs to happen on the image below. The black border represent the viewport, the red border represent the content container. The first row is the initial state, the other 2 rows show the position of the slider after clicking the "prev" arrow:

[image]

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lol, I just had to do that same thing last week.  I set `slidesToShow:1` and `slidesToScroll:1`.  I also have `variableWidth:false`, though I'm not sure if that played into it.

The next step is to set a width on your slides in CSS to keep them from resizing out to fill the space:

**JS**

```
$('.slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: false
}
```

**CSS**

```
/*Just to make it not full width, for this example*/
.slider{
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/*Edit, forgot this important bit.  This keeps the other slides visible*/
.slick-list {
    overflow: visible;
}

.your_slide {
    width: 280px!important;
    height: 345px!important;
}
```

Comment: You need to have variableWidth set to true otherwise the nav miscalculates with amount to move the slides.

Answer (score 1):

i've faced this problem in my react code
the solution is to not give the .slick-slide {} any margins and if you want give spacing between your elements you should add gap to .slick-track {}
my code is this

```js
var settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: false,
    nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <SamplePrevArrow />,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 576,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

```css
    .slick-track {
                            display: flex;
                            gap: 16px;
                              .slick-slide {
                                padding: 24px;
                                border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
                                background-color: $header-color;
                                border-radius: 15px;
                                margin-right: 0px;
                                direction: rtl;
                                min-height: 290px;
                                }
                                }
```

my settings handles the responsiveness too